# Get Browser Hotkey Settings Using JavaScript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Is there any way to use JavaScript (or HTML5 if necessary) to retrieve the browser's current settings on hotkeys? Notice that I am not trying to modify the settings, just trying to retrieve it.

Comment: Short answer is almost certainly no, but what setting are you looking to detect specifically?

Comment: Mostly to retrieve the current fullscreen hotkey setting, and display it on the page.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a bad question.  Maybe you could add a little to the question body what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, your best bet for this is to use browser sniffing, and compile a list of known hotkeys.

For example, using the [jQuery Client plugin](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/), something like:

```
var fullscreen = {
    Windows: {
        MSIE: 'Alt+F11',
        Firefox: 'Alt+F11'
    },
    Mac: {
        Firefox: 'Shift+Command+F'
    }
};

if(fullscreen[$.client.os] && fullscreen[$.client.os][$.client.browser]) {
    // render the label
}
```

Of course, this is a bit of a PITA.

Comment: So if a user has modified it's default hotkeys using keyconfig etc., there is no way to tell about it, yes?

Comment: Correct.  But, that would *usually* be a power user, so they can probably figure it out.  Most people don't even know that it is possible to change hotkeys!

Comment: I should have added that you probably can do this server-side as well, if you have a decent server-side language with a client detection library.  It would send less stuff to the client, as well.

Comment: Well that sounds like a reasonable argument =) Thanks for your help!